# Where is the saml authentication request is getting generated in Spring Security Saml Sample

Tags: spring, security, authentication, request, saml

I am learning to implement Saml, so far i have downloaded a sample of spring security with saml from this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/tree/master/sample , went through the reference guide and various other SAML links.

One thing which i need to ask is, as the Service Provider has to send the Saml AuthRequest where do we define it in the program.

I have tried to implement the sample and created dummy projects to work it with OpenAM, which is working fine for SSO, but I didn't understand from where the Saml Auth Request is getting generated.

*`I got to know that the SP's system itself is going to generate authentication request and send it to IDP using SAML 2.0 protocol. I need help about the parameters i need to pass so that i can customize my own saml authentication request`*

Any Help is Highly Appreciated!. Thanks in Advance. (I know its a stupid question to ask, but couldn't help it as I am failing to get any idea.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authentication request is performed according to the *authentication provider* selected and the configuration of your *filter chain*. Some details of those aspects are transparent while using an high-level framework like Spring.
Spring SAML is based on the OpenSAML library, providing a set of facilities in order to easily handle the whole AuthN process for Spring applications.

Indeed, to properly complete this process, you need to setup your application endpoint (entityID), the certificates to verify the parties' identity, secure your application paths, configure the binding protocols, establish a trust relationship between an IdP and your application exchanging some metadata.

For instance, consider the code stub as follows, taken from **[vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample)**:

```
@Bean
public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
    MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
    metadataGenerator.setEntityId("com:vdenotaris:spring:sp");
    metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
    metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
    metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager()); 
    return metadataGenerator;
}
```

You can check my custom parameters for the metadata generation, customizing my application settings for the SAML-based SSO.

The AuthN request is typically performed by redirecting the user on a third-party resource (i.e. a website), where provide the credentials. After the verification, the IdP sends a SAML envelope to the requester application (Service Provider), containing user information.

Comment: thank you so much, it has cleared my mind a lot, but I read somewhere that we need to bind our authrequest into HTTP or SOAP request, can we do it using the opensaml libraries?, another query of mine is that what if i need to add xacml into the auth request then would I need to customize in the metadatagenerator class itself

Comment: ok i have updated my understandings. Now i am into Saml 2.0 Profile of XACML 2.0, I understood that i have to define properties like bindings into saml entry point to implement XACML, am i right? I want use forgerock openam and implement it with SAML, can you please guide for that what should i read to get to the first step.